# How to show total profit for each month, show null when there is no record in that month in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

i am producing a report to show the total profit of each month IN 2018, and show NIL when there is no profit earned in certain months

the profit earned = 0.1 * Total_payment.
The PROFIT is earned when the service is done, the column "Total_payment" is come from the table BOOKING, i have to join BOOKING and SERVICE in order to get the total profit of each month, Booking_num is the key for joining BOOKING and SERVICE, Actual_end is the end date of the service

Now the problem is there is no profit earned in jan,feb and aug.
is there anyway to show NIL in profit column FOR THIS THREE MONTH?

```
SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM Actual_end) AS MONTH,SUM(Total_payment *0.1) AS PROFIT
FROM SERVICE,BOOKING
WHERE SERVICE.Booking_num = BOOKING.Booking_num
AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM Actual_end) = 2018
GROUP BY EXTRACT(MONTH FROM Actual_end);
```

This is the code of showing profit for 9 months,without jan,feb and aug

```
MONTH  PROFIT
3      88.4
4      146.1
5      112.6
6      108.3
7      102.6
9      130.3
10     72.6
12     124.9
```

I expect the output to be

```
MONTH    PROFIT
1        NIL
2        NIL
3        88.4
4        146.1 
5        112.6
6        108.3
7        102.6
8        NIL
9        130.3
10       72.6
11       124.9
12       25.2
```

how do i modify it, i have also tried

```
WITH CALENDAR AS(
SELECT TO_CHAR(add_months(date '2018-01-01',ROWNUM -1),'MM') AS MONTH
FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <=12)
SELECT CALENDER.MONTH, NVL(SUM(Total_payment*0.1),null) AS PROFIT
FROM BOOKING,SERVICE,CALENDER
WHERE BOOKING.Booking_num = SERVICE.Booking_num
AND CALENDER.MONTH = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM Actual_end(+))
AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM Actual_end) = 2018
GROUP BY CALENDER.MONTH
```

THE OUTPUT:
NO ROWS SELECTED

Comment: You need to make a thing which is called a calender table or use a delivered table (oracle calls it inline view in the manual i believe)  but instead of storing dates you store the numbers of the month..  When left joining the data  with that calender  table or delivered table on the month number you will get those missing values as `NULL`

Comment: if you still can't figure it out .. See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Qualify your column names so it is clear where the columns come from!

Answer (score 2):

You need and outer join(left or right). Btw, get rid of old-fashioned comma seperated join among tables, rather, use explicit join.

Add `RIGHT JOIN (SELECT LEVEL AS MNT FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 12 ) MNT` to your query if returning one certain year with whole months is the matter :

```
SELECT MNT AS MONTH,NVL(TO_CHAR(SUM(Total_payment *0.1)),'NIL') AS PROFIT
  FROM SERVICE S
  JOIN BOOKING B
    ON S.Booking_num = B.Booking_num
 RIGHT JOIN (SELECT LEVEL AS MNT 
               FROM DUAL 
             CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 12 ) MNT
         ON MNT.MNT = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM Actual_end) 
           AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM Actual_end)=2018                     
GROUP BY MNT
ORDER BY MONTH;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=41ce78fed5e8dc55cbae3baba4b6f7d1)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

In this case you need a list of all months:

```
with months as (
      select 1 as month from dual union all
      select 2 as month from dual union all
      select 3 as month from dual union all
      select 4 as month from dual union all
      select 5 as month from dual union all
      select 6 as month from dual union all
      select 7 as month from dual union all
      select 8 as month from dual union all
      select 9 as month from dual union all
      select 10 as month from dual union all
      select 11 as month from dual union all
      select 12 as month from dual
     )
select m.month, sum(s.total_payment * 0.1) as profit
from months m left join
     booking b
     on extract(month from b.actual_end) = m.month and
        b.actual_end >= date '2018-01-01' and
        b.actual_end < date '2019-01-01' left join
     service s join
     on s.booking_num = b.booking_num 
group by m.month;
```

Note:

- This is guessing that `actual_end` is in `booking` and `total_payment` is in `service`.  The query would be slightly different if this guess is not correct.
- *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.
- This query should use `LEFT JOIN`.  The first table has all the rows that you want.
- Filters on subsequent tables go in the `on` clause, not the `where` clause.
- Note the use of date constants.  Such comparisons usually make it easier for the engine to optimize the query (typically by using indexes).

Comment: but how do i show NIL in the profit column when there is no profit in that month?

Comment: @fayelan . . . This query should show `NULL` which is what SQL does in this situation.